# i need to print only once as i am getting it printed twice using regex in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
importre
list = re.findall('SF:((/\w*)*.c$)','SF:/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/https_util.c')
print(list)
```

#### output:

```
[('/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/https_util.c', '/https_util')]
```

but i need only:

```
/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/https_util.c
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case instead of using findall you can use search and get the respective group as shown below

```
import re
list = re.search('SF:((/\w*)*.c$)','SF:/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/https_util.c')
print(list.group(1))
```

Comment: i need to read a line that ends with .c As i'm using .c$ in python 2.7 version as its not printing

Comment: yes its working but its reading the line that ends with .cc as i need to read a line that only ends with .c not .cc